# Linked dropdown with comboboxes

Tags: vb.net, combobox

In my project there are 2 comboboxes.
These are called cbPricingText & cbPricingVal respectively.

What I want is that the DropDown for these 2 comboboxes become synchronized. I.e when one opens, so does the other and same on closing.

So far I've tried using the following code in the `.DropDown`-event and in the `.Click`-event alike.

```
Private Sub cbPricingVal_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cbPricingVal.Click
    If cbPricingVal.DroppedDown = False Then
        cbPricingVal.DroppedDown = True
    End if
End Sub
```

Putting the code in the `.DropDown`-event caused a never ending loop that crashed the app (the event triggers before the actual action so the events for the 2 comboboxes triggers eachother with no end).

Putting it in the `.Click`event did *almost* work. The clicked box drops first as it should but when it's brother-box drops a moment after, the original immediately closes.

Is my goal even possible and if so, does anyone have an idea of how to do it?

EDIT:
It's likely that the process of dropping combobox2 shifts focus away from combobox1 and this is what causes the closure. Is it possible to remove the `.DropDown` event from the combobox and then re-adding it?

Somthing like the following perhaps? (exept I'm terrible at eventhandling and this didn't work at all)

```
Private Sub cbPricingVal_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cbPricingVal.Click
    If cbPricingVal.DroppedDown = False Then
        RemoveHandler cboKCPricePerBadgeText.DropDownClosed, _
                      Windows.Forms.ComboBox.DropDownClosed       
        cbPricingVal.DroppedDown = True

        AddHandler cboKCPricePerBadgeText.DropDownClosed, _
                      Windows.Forms.ComboBox.DropDownClosed 
    End if
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you're using the "click" event, or drop down, they're calling each other over and over (hence the loop). You might want to do the "index changed" event instead.  It isn't at the exact same time (one after another instead) when they drop down, but you probably don't want that anyway. If they drop down at the same time, the user may try to edit both at the same time when they should edit one at a time.

```
 Private Sub cbPricingText_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbPricingText.SelectedIndexChanged
    If cbPricingVal.DroppedDown = False Then
        cbPricingVal.DroppedDown = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Having both boxes down at the same time is actually precisely what I wish for. What your code does is to drop the other box once the first closes down (has gotten a new SelectedIndex)
And regarding the loop, I do know that the `.DropDown` calls each other over and over but the `.Click` does not. Issue there is probably that the combobox closes when focus shifts to it's "brother".

Comment: Then I would use a separate event that happens without the combo box items actually affected ,and put droppeddown = true for both of them. Like mouse enter, a button, or scroll.

Comment: That is a pretty good suggestion.
Might not have time to implement today but I will see if I can make it work and update question accordingly.

Comment: I did experiment around a bit with setting `.DroppedDown = True` from other sources, such as a button but to no avail.
There seems to be something preventing 2 comboboxes being open simultaneously.